# Decrypting a one-time pad with a bias around letter 'L' with solution options.

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

Can someone please explain how this is done, I have the cypher text and 3 options for plain text. The cypher text is encrypted with a one time pad with a key where the letter 'L' was used too often.

Cyphertext:
NLBYVBDNSBWBCXEOPPBUDLKEZJOGKLIFYSLKHQKGRWIVFSZWWUCKHZIVWQELHWOIYZPIVKHRYAIZHHQWLIGPQXPQYTREHOGQFZNZEAKJEPMOHNIBZTOWBGYVESZSWYLRHCYZUDVAWLLHMERJTLWVTLOJDEAVYRBOEVGZQEREZUGDGTREWRIMDPZJLBVWTXVBQAGTTYYBZTWCNSOZWPMXVXNAPNWWGATQRLNYESRIFQEAMRCTSKZNILTTQJLOKRSVWVUWHCRJRQZXJXQWFEQIRESCEPGVFBLBPVGQCKEMLMXUHWKGWRGCOUPOPTMSDJJUFYDFBXFMPPJQXEVCJBTOGGUKZQZWQKYMWHSLWHIBRHPTQDUIZDAVUPGPPWSWYZPRYJPLSMIQYIMDGCZL

Plaintext option 1:
ITWASABRIGHTCOLDDAYINAPRILANDTHECLOCKSWERESTRIKINGTHIRTEENWINSTONSMITHHISCHINNUZZLEDINTOHISBREASTINANEFFORTTOESCAPETHEVILEWINDSLIPPEDQUICKLYTHROUGHTHEGLASSDOORSOFVICTORYMANSIONSTHOUGHNOTQUICKLYENOUGHTOPREVENTASWIRLOFGRITTYDUSTFROMENTERINGALONGWITHHIMTHEHALLWAYSMELTOFBOILEDCABBAGEANDOLDRAGMATSATONEENDOFITACOLOUREDPOSTERTOOLARGEFORINDOORDISPLAYHADBEENTACKEDTOTHEWALLITDEPICTEDSIMPLYANENORMOUSFACEMORE

Plaintext option 2:
CALLMEISHMAELSOMEYEARSAGONEVERMINDHOWLONGPRECISELYHAVINGLITTLEORNOMONEYINMYPURSEANDNOTHINGPARTICULARTOINTERESTMEONSHOREITHOUGHTIWOULDSAILABOUTALITTLEANDSEETHEWATERYPARTOFTHEWORLDITISAWAYIHAVEOFDRIVINGOFFTHESPLEENANDREGULATINGTHECIRCULATIONWHENEVERIFINDMYSELFGROWINGGRIMABOUTTHEMOUTHWHENEVERITISADAMPDRIZZLYNOVEMBERINMYSOULWHENEVERIFINDMYSELFINVOLUNTARILYPAUSINGBEFORECOFFINWAREHOUSESANDBRINGINGUPTHER

Plaintext option 3:
ITWASTHEBESTOFTIMESITWASTHEWORSTOFTIMESITWASTHEAGEOFWISDOMITWASTHEAGEOFFOOLISHNESSITWASTHEEPOCHOFBELIEFITWASTHEEPOCHOFINCREDULITYITWASTHESEASONOFLIGHTITWASTHESEASONOFDARKNESSITWASTHESPRINGOFHOPEITWASTHEWINTEROFDESPAIRWEHADEVERYTHINGBEFOREUSWEHADNOTHINGBEFOREUSWEWEREALLGOINGDIRECTTOHEAVENWEWEREALLGOINGDIRECTTHEOTHERWAYINSHORTTHEPERIODWASSOFARLIKETHEPRESENTPERIODTHATSOMEOFITSNOISIESTAUTHORITIESINSIS

The solution to the cypher text is one of the above solutions.

Comment: For each possible plaintext, you should be able to fully reconstruct the exact one time pad that would give the cipher text. Does one of these pads have the property you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Making the same (standard) encoding assumptions: encryption is addition modulo 26, while letters A-Z correspond to 0-25.

One easily (I did it in Python; less tedious) computes the pads that must have been used if plain1, plain2 and plain3 would have been the true plaintext:
(not as digits as but as letters):

`pad1 = FSFYDBCWKVPIAJTLMPDMQLVNRYOTHSBBWHXIXYOCASQCOKPOJOJDZIPRSDIDUEVULHDACDAJGYBRUUWXMXCMIKWCRLZDQKGYMRAZRWFEQYTVTJQZZEKDUCDNTODKJVTGZNJVRNBSUBAJTXAVZFPCMHIYDMISKDKWQQLROLDNBIGQOLDREYBYJJSWXIFCLVLQSWTFZSRILEFYSOBGWXQPEMZVJWODNCQWZSIHQGNVMMNSZLCIEXTRASMMIXSHGKSKLZUYPQNYYCUWVPFSCCQHQEMYECDHUYUBJJGXKKLYYITHEIFYDREODGVXLQXELQFDMKPUBGZIKBSIKBHOSYLWRVUMSQWVMGLTWFIHTOUIKDTTFSMPWZLNSWCMXOGHNBPEUWBUGYOYTIKZUOIH`

`pad2=LLQNJXVVLPWXRFQCLRXUMTKYLWKLGUWXLPEWLFWTLHRRDKHSLWVKMRVPLILSWSARLLDUIGJJLOKKNQYSLVDCCEIILNCEQVYOLONILMCWLLVKPUWXLGWPNPUNLLLYQRSJLOEORLVSLLKTSLRYLSDKPLBGLAWCRNFOLRPBBEALLPNWCXDNLOATVXZNLDNPTCRNLXPLYQLVLORJGOWKLLIKVKKJLHCLGHLDLSGUCKAGLFEHEDPXLGMJNHCLLBYLYTARLQOFTGJWLKIPXXPILLXBNSEILIKOBOHGLEYXUSEJLAIRQOLHLTTOTQDNLCEFRLRGLNHYXKBRLYBLPRSQLJPDBYHPLFFJXKHELJDLCPAOLGLOCMQGLYVNHTGYLPECGVXRLGOUKZCILCSONVVU`

`pad3 = FSFYDIWJRXEIOSLGDLJMKPKMGCKKWUQMKNSCVMSYYAIDMLVWQQOFLRQSIEWSLWWPRVPCRWCMKMXRPADSTQYWUXXXRPNPTMZCAYJOWWFBLTMWOGEXKFMPNBQICBVPCNDYJUFDULCTSTHHUQEVOAOPMSGQHEICRNJKEDSMCZOEIKTZOBJLARQTWLHUUTIQFSONBWYAXYGISPAUAZKIIKJTDINSYRSPGXPVNUPFXKECEMZMVNIBWGSNFYFAJBYIJNNHFRAELYVFAMZMYRCOSYNAAAQJLBZRFGHOTRKMLGEBAGJMUQHYFNEJVNLAWMIBHJLMSGWRKEMFLAFZPQSGJJBABGDZRGVDJGJVSPOYDSEKJTMAJDBQLRWHPHNXCIKEQVXYYPWEEVAXQEUVTKRT`

with 18, 77 and 16 'L''s respectively. So text 2 is the original plaintext, clearly, and pad2 the key. (The expected number of L's is 400 (size of pad) / 26 = 15.3, so the first and last values are quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the one-time pad is being used as follows.  Each letter A to Z in plaintext and pad is interpreted as number $0$ to $25$, added mod $26$, and then translated back to letters.

If the plaintext is typical of English text, it will have the typical letter distribution (in particular more than 12% E).  Those E positions where the one-time pad has L will translate E to P.  The cyphertext has 400 letters, of which 21 are P, in positions 
$17, 18, 67, 84, 87, 106, 182, 210, 217, 282, 289, 311, 313, 329, 330, 363, 374, 376, 377, 383, 387$.

The E's in the three plaintexts are in the following positions:
$$\eqalign{\text{option } 1:& 32, 40, 42, 56, 57, 83, 94, 102, 110, 115, 118, 122, 132, 150, 194, 204, 206, 231, 234, 253, 263, 272, 280, 298, 299, 313, 319, 328, 349, 350, 356, 362, 370, 375, 385, 396, 400\cr
\text{option }2:& 6, 12, 17, 19, 27, 29, 44, 48, 62, 70, 80, 106, 108, 112, 119, 149, 154, 155, 158, 162, 173, 191, 206, 210, 211, 217, 228, 242, 244, 246, 256, 277, 285, 287, 289, 310, 313, 325, 327, 329, 339, 363, 367, 377, 382, 399\cr
\text{option }3:& 8, 10, 18, 27, 38, 47, 50, 66, 69, 80, 90, 91, 99, 102, 111, 112, 123, 137, 139, 158, 160, 172, 182, 194, 202, 207, 212, 219, 223, 225, 234, 238, 242, 254, 258, 262, 264, 266, 278, 284, 287, 290, 292, 294, 306, 311, 315, 329, 331, 347, 350, 353, 355, 359, 371, 382, 394\cr}$$

Option 1 has only one E in the same position where the cyphertext has P, 
while option 2 has $9$ and option 3 has $4$.

So my vote is for option 2.